# Laravel resource controller method not invoked

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.6

I have controllers `LeadsController`, `LeadsAttributesController` and `LeadsReminderController`

```
Route::resource('leads' , 'LeadsController');
Route::prefix('leads')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('attributes' , 'LeadAttributesController' , ['as' => 'leads']);
    Route::resource('reminders' , 'LeadRemindersController' , ['as' => 'leads']);
});
```

When I go to `/leads/attributes` the framework should call the index function, but in this case, a blank page appears and no any exception is shown. However, the route to `/leads/attributes/create` works as it should.

If the routes are restructured as below, then the routing works fine

```
Route::prefix('leads')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('attributes' , 'LeadAttributesController' , ['as' => 'leads']);
    Route::resource('reminders' , 'LeadRemindersController' , ['as' => 'leads']);
});
Route::resource('leads' , 'LeadsController');
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour of the framework?

Comment: Can you go to .env file and set the APP_DEBUG=true and then try. You will get the exact error.

Comment: Your ‘leads/attributes’ uri end up calling ‘LeadController@show’ so better replace prefix with little different

Comment: @HassanRaza I am working with development environment and the debug option is set to true

Comment: @Purvesh You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get around this is to put the LeadsController routes under the group routes:

```
Route::prefix('leads')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('attributes' , 'LeadAttributesController' , ['as' => 'leads']);
    Route::resource('reminders' , 'LeadRemindersController' , ['as' => 'leads']);
});
Route::resource('leads' , 'LeadsController');
```

The reason you have to do this is because the wildcard for the `leads` show route will accept anything as default. When laravel receives a request it will try and match it to the first route that it can so since your `leads` resource is above your nested resources it will match to the show method of leads rather than the correct nested resource.

Comment: Thanks but I needed to know the reason why. This is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @BirendraGurung I've added an explanation to my answer, if you're still stuck on it just let me know.